# How to make the ImageField optional in django rest framework API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty tired finding solution to make the imagefield optional in django rest framework API. I tried each and every solution I found in stack overflow but nothing seems to be working fine. I know there are fewer posts related to same query but I didn't find the solution in that.

Let me explain you what is my requirements.
Here is my User model with some basic info fields including an Image field.

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[firstname_check])
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, validators=[lastname_check])
username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, validators=[username_check])
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, validators=[password_check])
mobnum = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, validators=[mobile_num_len])
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
language = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to ='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
from utils import Base64ImageField
class UserMannualSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 profile_img = Base64ImageField(
     max_length=None, use_url=True, allow_empty_file=True, required=False
      )

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'mobnum',
        'gender',
        'language',
        'timestamp'
        'profile_img'
    ]
```

Here is the Base64ImageField() function which I've written inside the utils.py file. Which will take the base64 string and convert it back and store in the server and that is happening properly. But when I don't upload the image, it throws an error. If I pass the (allow_empty_file=True, required=False) attributes and its values in the Base64ImageField(), even also it doesn't work at all.

**utils.py**

```
class Base64ImageField(serializers.ImageField):
"""
A Django REST framework field for handling image-uploads through raw post data.
It uses base64 for encoding and decoding the contents of the file.

Heavily based on
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1268

Updated for Django REST framework 3.
"""

def to_internal_value(self, data):

    # Check if this is a base64 string
    if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
        # Check if the base64 string is in the "data:" format
        if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
            # Break out the header from the base64 content
            header, data = data.split(';base64,')

        # Try to decode the file. Return validation error if it fails.
        try:
            decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
        except TypeError:
            self.fail('invalid_image')

        # Generate file name:
        file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12] # 12 characters are more than enough.
        # Get the file name extension:
        file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)

        complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension, )

        data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)

    return super(Base64ImageField, self).to_internal_value(data)

def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decoded_file):
    import imghdr

    extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
    extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension

    return extension
```

Note: If I give default field in the ImageField, then also it's not working. It's not taking the default image if I don't upload one.

I'm working with Python 3.6, Django 3.1.1, djangorestframework 3.11.1

Please let me know if someone has already been faced this problem and got the solution or any alternative would also help. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

### Edited part

Here is the code from another app, how I'm sending the code from the other django app.

```
def register_confirm(request):
"""
getting the sign-up required values
dumping the all the parameters as json
using requests library to achieve the register via API
passing the success response to profile.html
"""
std_mobnum = ''
if request.method == "POST":
    firstname = request.POST.get("fname")
    lastname = request.POST.get("lname")
    username = request.POST.get("uname")
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    password = request.POST.get("pswd")
    mobnum = request.POST.get("mobnum")
    image = request.POST.get('imagtobase64')
    gender = request.POST.get("gender")
    language = request.POST.get("language")
    params={
        
        'firstname':firstname,
        'lastname':lastname,
        'username':username,
        'email':email,
        'password':password,
        'mobnum':mobnum,
        'profile_img':image,
        'gender':gender,
        'language':language,
    }
    

    print(params)

    headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}
    response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-create/", data=json.dumps(params),  headers=headers)
    user_data = response.json()
    print(user_data)
    return JsonResponse(user_data)
```

Note: I'm sending the base64 string of an image using jquery to Api.

This is the code of views.py file where I'm handling the serializer and post request.

**views.py**

```
api_view(['POST'])
```

@parser_classes([MultipartJsonParser, FormParser, JSONParser])

def userCreate(request):

```
status=''
message = ''
data ={}
try:
    mannualSerializer = UserMannualSerializer(data = request.data)
    print("serializer started")
    if mannualSerializer.is_valid():
       print("form validated")
       mannualSerializer.save()
       print("saved")
       status='success'
       message = 'User created successfully.'
       data= mannualSerializer.data

 except Exception as error:
    status='failure'
    message = error
 response = {
        "status":status,
        "message":message,
        "data":data
        }
 return Response(response)
```

Comment: settings `required=False` will do the job ***normally***. What error you have got? Can you show the payload that you have sent?

Comment: Actually, it's not passing serializers.valid() and it's throwing error : {'status': 'failure', 'message': {'profile_img': ['The submitted file is empty.']}, 'data': {}}.

Comment: Does your payload have `profile_img` field? Make a payload that doesn't have the `profile_img` field and try again

Comment: Yes I've profile_image field in the payload. Because, while uploading the image it's happening. But, it throws error if I don't select an image. It takes the profile_img field as mandatory one which shouldn't be.

Comment: You shouldn't include that field in the payload. If you include, DRF thinks there is some data associated with the field and gets validated and hence the error. So, omit that field if you are not sending an image (I am damn sure that it is possible).

Comment: Thanks for help. I would like to share you few more code lines. How could I do that? Shall I press "Answer your question" button and share you the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222511/discussion-between-prakash-madariya-and-arakkal-abu).

Comment: Hi @Arakkal Abu. Please check the edited part in the question.

Comment: Hii, @Arakkal Abu. Thank you so much. Previously, I was bit confused about your last answer. Now, I got it. So, now as you said, if there is image, I can add the profile_image attribute to the payload else I'll not add this attribute and now doing so giving me output as expected. I appreciate your time.